# sendmsg: Network is unreachable

Tags: networking, ip, ping

I set the IP address of my network card to a particular value to be able to talk to a piece of hardware. Then I try to ping it, which works for a few seconds, until I get the error

```
ping: sendmsg: Network is unreachable
```

I can then reset the IP address and ping the hardware again.

It does not seem to be a hardware issue. I can wiggle the cable without getting disconnected, and I can sit as still as I can and I still get disconnected.

`dmesg` is not showing anything.

The ping is working seemingly forever on one computer, but not on another one. What could cause the interrupts? How can I debug this?

Comment: @MelBurslan There is no other machine in the network. My computer is connected to the piece of hardware and that's it.

Comment: Oops I deleted my comment. Sorry. can you post the output of `ifconfig -a` from this computer and the other one which pings fine, on your original post ?

Comment: What does `tcpdump` or `wireshark` show happening?

Comment: It's ICMP  messages. check your firewall , or any banning program.

Comment: I will check with `tcpdump` and/or `wireshark`, thanks for the tip. I don't know what to check on the "firewall or any banning program".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the following file:

```
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
```

with the line

```
BOOTPROTO="dhcp"
```

in it. So when I assigned a static IP address to the computer, after a while it would try to renegiotiate with the DHCP server, which wasn't available. Removing the whole file worked for me. Hence I'm not sure it really is the line quoted above, that was causing the disconnect.